# How is net income in Netherlands calculated?

Tags: income-tax, netherlands

I've recently got a job in Amsterdam in one of the Dutch-based companies. The offer that I've received has the following components:

- Gross: 45600 EUR (3800/month)
- Holiday Bonus: 3648 EUR
- Pension/year: 861 EUR
- Bonus: 3500 EUR

resulting in a total of 53609 EUR. The recruiter tells me that I am applicable for the 30% tax ruling, however, I may not get the entire 30% considering that I have only a Bachelor's degree and age is below 30.

I was under the impression that the 30% was a fixed value rather than a maximum possible one. Can anyone please clarify this?

Also, based on the above data, could anyone also help me in calculating the net income(in-hand) that I'll be getting per month?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The "below 30" rule applies only in combination with a recognized master title, but that's chiefly intended to cover PhD students. They would still qualify for that 30%. Typical PhD pay doesn't meet the income check, so that's why the income check is set lower or waived for them. Your 45K is sufficiently far above the income bar that it is not problem in any case.

Still, you should have been given a tax status ruling by your employer. The 30% only applies after the Tax Office approves it, and only for the period of the ruling. (Typically 8 years).

Note that the 30% is a lump sum deduction. It replaces individual deductions that would otherwise apply. Those other deductions generally do not add up to 30%, which is probably what your recruiter was hinting at. Besides being lower, those deductions are also a bigger hassle. You might want a tax advisor for that.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to use this calculator (in Dutch) given the complexity of the system:
https://prepay.adp.nl/#!/inpt

In the calculator you can take the 30% tax ruling into account. However whether or not this applies to you I can't say.

Your holiday bonus and normal bonus will also be taxed and I assume your pension contributions will also be deducted from your gross salary or is this on top?

Comment: Thanks Karl. Pension contributions are on top of my gross salary. As far as calculating monthly income is concerned, I found a good example on the below link which in a way helped me in determining my net income if I exclude the holiday allowance and bonus for the time being.

http://www.expatica.com/nl/finance/Tax-exemption-Dutch-30-percent-ruling-explained_101641.html